# How do I to build and then populate a multi-tab excel spreadsheet using an SSIS package?

Tags: sql, ssis

I currently have a package that creates an excel spreadsheet with multiple tabs, and it names each column in each tab.  Later in the package, I have excel connections that select my data using queries and populates each column in each tab based on the mappings I define.  This has worked for a long time, but since a driver update, my OLE DB connections wont let me create the excel spreadsheet anymore. The key here is that the package needs to be able to be called by a scheduling system and be totally hands off and self sufficient.  Also, the excel spreadsheet is created brand new with every execution of the package so we can keep an archive of old reports.

I've tried to use the existing excel connections to also build the spreadsheet, but I don't see a way to populate multiple tabs in the same spreadsheet with excel connections.

Is there a better way to do this without having to do a C# script.

Comment: Forgive the smart answer, but a better way would be to use a proper reporting tool like SSRS for example. Or do you need this file to have editable cells? Could you perhaps post more details around the driver update and explain why it won't let you create sheets? i.e. an error message

Comment: And have you looked into rolling back those driver changes?

Comment: are you able to execute the package in debugging mode and the issue occurs only when running through scheduled job?

Comment: I spoke with our DBA and they prefer not to roll back or “repair” the patch on the server that affected the driver. So that’s not an option. 

I was able to fix the connection issue by switching the ole db connections to excel connections within the spreadsheet creation step. Problem solved.